Couldn't the Jews eat their livestock in addition to eating the manna in the Exodus period?
The Jews were tired of eating the manna day by day (Numbers 11:6-9) which the Lord had given them (Exodus 16:31-35). Yet God instituted the offering of sacrifices at the tabernacle (Leviticus 1-7). If they had livestock for the sacrifices, why could they not eat them in addition to the manna the Lord supplied during their wilderness travels?
They grew tired of the manna. Could it be that they ran out of livestock and had to rely on manna only?

Eating the livestock would not make them last.  However, I imagine that the occasional animal was killed for food, even for sacrifices which were many.

Short Answer: Scripture does not say for certain.
We do know that the Israelites had livestock that they could have used for sacrifices and potentially for food. This would be in addition to the manna provided by the Lord while in the wilderness.
Exodus 12:38 records that the Israelites brought flocks and herds out of Egypt.
Exodus 12:37-39 NKJV

37 Then the children of Israel journeyed from Rameses to Succoth,
about six hundred thousand men on foot, besides children. 38 A mixed
multitude went up with them also, and flocks and herds—a great deal of
livestock. 39 And they baked unleavened cakes of the dough which they
had brought out of Egypt; for it was not leavened, because they were
driven out of Egypt and could not wait, nor had they prepared
provisions for themselves.

And we also see that they had livestock available for sacrifices at the tabernacle (Leviticus 1-7).
I want to note that the dissatisfaction expressed by the Israelites with the manna, according to Numbers 11:6-9, was due to their longing for the variety of foods they had enjoyed in Egypt, rather than just meat.
Numbers 11:4-6 NKJV

4 Now the mixed multitude who were among them yielded to intense
craving; so the children of Israel also wept again and said: “Who will
give us meat to eat? 5 We remember the fish which we ate freely in
Egypt, the cucumbers, the melons, the leeks, the onions, and the
garlic; 6 but now our whole being is dried up; there is nothing at all
except this manna before our eyes!”

They remembered the fish, cucumbers, melons, leeks, onions, and garlic they had eaten in Egypt including a desire for meat.
Based on this, what are some possibilities? [1]

The Israelites were tired of eating the same things time and time again. They were simply complaining because they wanted variety rather than because they had absolutely no meat.
In ancient Egypt, people worshiped various animals, including cattle. After leaving Egypt, the Israelites also started worshiping a golden calf made by Aaron while Moses was away (Exodus 32:1–4). It's possible that they may have been influenced by Egyptian beliefs to the point where they couldn't consume animals they considered sacred.
They planned to sell their livestock later and therefore they didn't want to eat them.
The Israelites had limited or nearly exhausted their supply of livestock during  their prolonged wilderness journey.


Rabbi Avraham Ibn Ezra suggests that they had already eaten a large
portion of their cattle. A this point, if they would all go to
purchase more meat at once, the price would skyrocket beyond their
means. [2]


Killing a large animal affords a person an abundance of food at one time. After that, since they didn't port refrigerators around in the wilderness, it had to be salted and eaten cold. It's possible that the Israelites wanted smaller animals so they could enjoy fresh meat on demand. [2]

Of course, it is possible that the Israelites eventually exhausted their supply of livestock during their prolonged wilderness journey. It's very likely that they used some of their livestock for sacrifices and provisions. Of course, this could lead to a decrease in their herds and flocks over time. If we want to account for all variables we should also include natural factors such as disease and predators which could have decreased the size and influenced the health of their livestock.
Regardless of the specific reasons, the focus was on faith and obedience. It gives a lesson for us to trust in God's provision and remaining faithful to His commands even in challenging circumstances.

According to Exodus 12:6, Passover occurred on Nissan 14, and the Israelites departed from Egypt on Nissan 15. In Exodus Chapter 16, we learn that Manna was provided to the Israelites on the fifteenth day of the second month. Consequently, the Israelites relied on the provisions they had brought with them for an entire month before receiving the manna.
Exodus 12:37 records that the Israelites, excluding women and children, numbered around six hundred thousand men on foot as they left Egypt. Considering that Israelite women bore many children, as mentioned in Exodus 1:20, it is possible the total population has about two millions.
Furthermore, Exodus 16:3 describes how the Israelites grumbled about the scarcity of meat, indicating that they had indeed depleted their livestock.
The Israelites were specifically instructed to consume manna in just the quantity they need. This practice symbolized God's ongoing provision and nourishment, without any excess or redundancy. To reinforce their faithfulness to God's provision, it is possible that the remaining livestock were divinely limited-sufficient for sacrificial rituals but not for sustenance. Additionally, the desert terrain could not support a large flock. As a result, quail was provided to the Israelites at night as a source of meat from that point onward (Exodus 16:12-13).
